# Manipulation or modification of array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I'm new to PHP. I'm doing one my project with php and I'm new to array functions and all those things. I have tried but not get success in that. let me show you my sql query array.
I have one my array which is as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-25
            [ufname] => Rutul
            [ulname] => Shah
            [name] =>  Clinic
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-26
            [ufname] => Rutul
            [ulname] => Shah
            [name] =>  Clinic
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-25
            [ufname] => Administrator
            [ulname] => Administrator
            [name] =>  Clinic
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-26
            [ufname] => Administrator
            [ulname] => Administrator
            [name] =>  Clinic
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-25
            [ufname] => Administrator
            [ulname] => Administrator
            [name] =>  Clinic
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-26
            [ufname] => Amit
            [ulname] => Mahida
            [name] => Cancer Specialist
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [pc_eventDate] => 2016-08-26
            [ufname] => Amit
            [ulname] => Mahida
            [name] => Breach Candy Hospital
        )

)
```

Now I want my resulted array as below :

```
Array
(
    [2016-08-25] => Array
        (
            [ Clinic] => Array
                (
                    [Rutul Shah] => Array
                        (
                            [appointments] => 1
                        )

                    [Administrator Administrator] => Array
                        (
                            [appointments] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

    [2016-08-26] => Array
        (
            [Clinic] => Array
                (
                    [Rutul Shah] => Array
                        (
                            [appointments] => 1
                        )
                    [Administrator Administrator] => Array
                        (
                            [appointments] => 1
                        )

                )
                [Cancer Specialist] => Array
                    (
                        [Amit Mahida] => Array
                            (
                                [appointments] => 1
                            )
                    )
                [Breach Candy Hospital] => Array
                    (
                        [Amit Mahida] => Array
                            (
                                [appointments] => 1
                            )
                    )

        )

)
```

Comment: which version of PHP are you running on?

Comment: My php version is 5.6.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to loop through your appointments array and use its contents to generate the other data structure.  let's call your first array `$input` and your second array `$output`:

```
// initialize output array
$output = [];

// loop through each $appt in the $input array
foreach($input as $appt) {
  // get shorter var names for appt data
  $date = $appt['pc_eventDate'];
  $name = $appt['name'];
  $uname = $appt['ufname'].' '.$appt['ulname'];

  // initialize each level of the data structure if it doesn't already exist
  if(!isset($output[$date])) $output[$date] = [];   
  if(!isset($output[$date][$name])) $output[$date][$name] = [];
  if(!isset($output[$date][$name][$uname])) $output[$date][$name][$uname] = [];
  // initialize the number of appts to 0
  if(!isset($output[$date][$name][$uname]['appointments'])) $output[$date][$name][$uname]['appointments'] = 0;

  // increment the number of appts
  $output[$date][$name][$uname]['appointments']++;
}
```

the important thing is the intialization of each sub-array in the new structure according to the data in the old structure -- from there we're just counting the number of appointments that match the new data.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Say the array is question is `$arr`

This will arrange the array in the way you wanted as solution

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value['pc_eventDate]))
          $value['pc_eventDate] = [];
    if(!is_array($value['pc_eventDate]['name'])) 
          $value['pc_eventDate]['name'] = []; 
    if(!is_array($value['pc_eventDate']['name']['ufname'.' ulname'])){
          $value['pc_eventDate']['name']['ufname'.' ulname'] = [];
           $value['pc_eventDate']['name']['ufname'.' ulname']['appointments'] = 1;
    }else{
         $value['pc_eventDate']['name']['ufname'.' ulname']['appointments'] += 1;
    }
}
```

You need to do something like the above.
Try running the above code, there could be some typo. If its doesnt yields your desired result, try commenting out all the lines in the body of the foreach and `var_dump()` each step to test the building of the array structure.

Thanks